# A 'script' named 'ContentPicker' could not be found

Tags: .net, content-management-system, orchardcms, orchardcms-1.6

I upgraded an Orchard 1.4 site with Orchard 1.6, by copying over the site.  I didn't have a menu before, but am now adding a menu, and am trying to add a content menu item.  When I click the add button in the navigation area of the admin app, I get the following error.  Any idea how to resolve this issue?

```
A 'script' named 'ContentPicker' could not be found.

Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code. 

Exception Details: System.InvalidOperationException: A 'script' named 'ContentPicker' could not be found.

Source Error: 


Line 13:     <meta charset="utf-8" />
Line 14:     <title>@Html.Title(title, siteName)</title> 
Line 15:     @Display(Model.Head)
Line 16:     <script>(function(d){d.className="dyn"+d.className.substring(6,d.className.length);})(document.documentElement);</script> 
Line 17: </head>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you upgraded by copying over the site and leaving the same database, some of the modules that would be enabled by default installation are left disabled.

One of those modules is `ContentPicker`. So, you just need to enable the module..

Comment: Thanks much!  For future readers, the exact location in 1.6 is under the "Input Editor" header, named Orchard.ContentPicker.